# Set width for column with react-export-excel

Tags: reactjs, export, export-to-excel

I'm using react-export-excel to export some data to a XLSX file.

I need to set a default width to each column of my sheet. I already followed the [example of the documentation](https://github.com/rdcalle/react-export-excel/blob/HEAD/examples/styled_excel_sheet.md) and tried to set my columns like this:

```
columns: [{
    value: "Column 1",
    widthPx: 250,
},{
    value: "Column 2",
    widthPx: 200,
},{
    value: "Column 3",
    widthPx: 200,
},{
    value: "Column 4",
    widthPx: 160,
}],
```

When I click to export my file with this code, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: s.t.match is not a function
at write_sst_xml (xlsx.js:4334)
```

This is the image of the error stack:

[image: Error stack]

My code only works if I set my columns like this:

```
columns: ["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4"]
```

But with this code, I'm not able to set the default width. Does anyone know the solution or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- Can try to upgrade version.
- Notice the `data` and `dataSet` when putting into

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @thinh I'm already using the latest version of `react-export-excel`. The author of this package created a new version of it with another name, called `react-data-export`, but this one doesn't work at all with my app.

Comment: About using `data` or `dataSet`, the only prop that works with me is `dataSet`. The app returns an error when I use just `data`.